# Set MinimumBlobArea with width and height - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have a project to detect an object with background subtraction. But I can only set minimumblobarea with minimum pixel.. in my case, I need to set minimunblobarea to detect object in width and height to get specific object.. example : if there is an object bigger than width and height that I've set before, that object can't be detected.. so what should I do?

I Use this code

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html

Comment: first you can provide a small example of input image and a bit of code? Do you have any other requirements in terms of functions you can/can't use for example?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Comment: Thanks 4 your comment.. I use this :obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
            'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
            'MinimumBlobArea', 400);             dthis is the source :http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html

Answer (score 1):

`vision.BlobAnalysis` returns bounding boxes of the detected blobs. The bounding box is a 4-element array of the form `[x, y, width, height]`. Once you have the bounding boxes you can easily check with ones have the  width or the height that is too big, and exclude them.

Let's say you have N bounding boxes returned by `vision.BlobAnalysys` as an N-by-4 matrix called `bboxes`. You can use logical indexing to find boxes that are too big:

```
bigBoxesIdx = (bboxes(:, 3) > maxWidth) | (bboxes(:,4) > maxHeight);
```

`bigBoxesIdx` is now a logical array, where you have 1's for boxes that are too big, and 0's for the ones that are not. Note that you have to use the `|`, which stands for "element-wise or", rather than `||`.

Now to throw away the boxes that are too big you simply do

```
bboxes(bigBoxesIdx, :) = [];
```

Comment: How I write that code.. sorry. -_-I am not familiar with matlab

Comment: Can you help me which one should be added to this code ? --> http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html

Comment: @user3811002 if you are not familiar with matlab, try [learning matlab](https://www.coursera.org/course/matlab) first. SO is a forum to ask for *help* where you struggle, not to ask people to *code* for you.